# Have Magento removed Mobile Menu from admin in version 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile, app

I have no idea that magento have **removed Mobile menu or it is not visible** on my setup. I have checked it in two websites, but I am not able to see it.

Can anyone clear my doubt that it is removed by magento or there is some problem in my setup? If there is problem then how to solve it. And if magento have removed this then **how to create a mobile app in magento**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It has been Removed

The Mobile menu was only used for the mobile app service that Magento provided a few years ago. That service hasn't been offered for a while, so the menu was removed in a recent update.

However If you see the code files you will find  **XML Connect Module** in `app/etc/modules`

Enable the module by changing it to

```
<active>true</active>
```